# why css background-color make td width increment

Tags: html, css

html struct like this:

```
<table class="barby-barcode">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="barby-row">
      <td class="barby-cell on"></td>
      <td class="barby-cell on"></td>
      <td class="barby-cell on"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css like this:

```
table.barby-barcode { border-spacing: 0; }
tr.barby-row { height: 100px; }
td.barby-cell { width: 3px; height: 3px; }
td.barby-cell.on { background: #000; }
```

but actually display is that td.barby-cell.on width is 5px, why the width increment

Answer (score 0):

First: The "table", "tr" and such is not necessary. ".barby-[sth]" is all that it needs to identify the class.

Second: Have you checked that margin, padding and border are all 0?